# Why am I getting undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x81c918> (NoMethodError)?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get albums.title (in the display_album method). Whenever I run the code through the terminal, it says undefine method 'title' for #. I think I put all instances correctly. I am not sure what I miss.

I tried to check if I put instances correctly and also debugging with p method to check if instance variables do not work across the class.

```
$genre = ['Null', 'Pop', 'Classic', 'Jazz', 'Rock']

class Album 
    attr_accessor :title, :artist, :genre, :tracks
    def initialize(title, artist, genre, tracks)
        @title = title
        @artist = artist
        @genre = genre
        @tracks = tracks  
    end
end 

def read_albums()
    puts "write a file name"
    afile = gets.chomp 

    file = File.new(afile, "r")
    albums = Array.new()
    if file 
         i =0 
         count = file.gets.to_i
         while i<count 
                albums << read_album(file) 
            i +=1 
        end   
    file.close
    end 
    albums
end

def read_album(file)
    album_title = file.gets
    album_artist = file.gets
    album_genre = file.gets
    album_tracks = read_tracks(file)
    album = Album.new(album_title, album_artist, album_genre, album_tracks) 
    album       
end

def display_albums(albums)
    finished = false 
    begin
    selection = read_integer_in_range("choose the number", 1, 3)
    case selection 
    when 1 
        display_album(albums) 
    when 2
        display_genres
    when 3
        finished = read_boolean 'Are you sure to exit ? (enter yes if yes)'
    else   
        puts 'Please select again'
    end 
    end  
end

def display_album(albums)
    puts "the album title is" + albums.title.to_s
end

def main_menu 
finished = false 
begin 
selection = read_integer_in_range('please select the number between 1 and 5', 1, 5)
case selection
when 1
    albums = read_albums
when 2
    display_albums(albums)
when 3
    play_album
when 4
    update_album
when 5
    finished = read_boolean 'Are you sure to exit ? (enter yes if yes)' 
else
      puts 'Please select again'
end 

end until finished
end  

main_menu
```

I expect to get a title name which is "Coldplay Viva la Vida or Death and All His Friends".

The error message I got is music_player.rb:103:in `display_album': undefined method`title' for # (NoMethodError)

Comment: The error is telling you that arrays don't have a `title` method. Which is correct. So, why are you trying to call `title` on an array? There's too much code in your question for me to find the problem, but the variable is called `albums` (album**s**, plural), so clearly you expect there to be multiple albums in that variable, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
def display_album(albums)
    puts "the album title is" + albums.title.to_s
end
```

You're feeding in an array of albums instead of one individual album. Change it to:

```
def display_album(album)
    puts "the album title is" + album.title.to_s
end
```

And when you call the method, make sure you call it with just one album as an argument rather than an array. The error is telling you you were calling the 'title' method on an array of albums, when you need to call it on just one item.